# jq simple json object merge/combination

Tags: json, object, merge, addition, jq

a.json

```
{"a": 1}
```

b.json

```
{"b": 1}
```

Desired outcome

```
{"a": 1, "b": 1}
```

---

> jq -s "." a.json b.json

```
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "b": 1
  }
]
```

It's wrapped in an array

---

> jq "." a.json b.json

```
{
  "a": 1
}
{
  "b": 1
}
```

That's not even valid json

---

Is jq the wrong tool here? What is more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
jq -s 'add' a.json b.json
```

Result:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases it may be desirable to avoid “slurping” the objects, as that requires more memory than necessary.

In any case, to accomplish the task economically, use -n in conjunction with `inputs` as follows:

```
reduce inputs as $i ({}; . + $i)
```

### sigma/1

If you don't mind that `sigma(empty)` evaluates to `null`, you could define a polymorphic `sigma` as follows:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (null; . +$x);
```

This works on streams of numbers, streams of objects, streams of arrays, and streams of strings, and so would be suitable for your standard library.

In any case, with this def, for the task at hand, you could write: `simga(inputs)`.